# redirection problem for my sites

Tags: apache-2.2, django, documentroot

I have a site `example.com` and another one `test.example.com`. Both have different configuration file. But when I enter url `test.example.com` it will redirect to `example.com`.

```
configuration file for example.com

 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot my-document-path

  Options -Indexes

  ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
  ErrorDocument 403 /errors/404.html

 <Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    PythonPath "['path', 'path'] + sys.path"
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE example.settings
    PythonInterpreter example
    PythonAutoReload On
    PythonDebug On
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few times, having multiple domain names defined, apache will load the first one.  
 
Did you define NameVirtualHost? Take a look at this reference: [NameVirtualHost Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a named virtual host will resolve the issue for you as above :)